# VSCode build task with dependsOn does "nothing" when gulp is installed. No output. How can I find the error?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I'm having problems with my VSCode installation, and I need some help to detect the cause of the error(s).

In one of my projects, I cannot (for some reason) execute any task that have "dependency tasks" defined. This is my `.vscode/tasks.json` file (created just to illustrate the problem):

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "subtask1",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "echo This is a subtask"
        },
        {
            "label": "all",
            "dependsOn": [
                "subtask1"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The task `subtask1` runs fine. The output is "This is a subtask".

However, the task `all` does not run. When I select it from the list of tasks to run, nothing happens. The terminal output remains unchanged (whatever output was already there, remains).

Whatever I name the tasks, doesn't matter. It seems that any task will not execute if it has a "dependsOrder" property defined.

This problem only persists when `gulp` is installed in the project dir (using `npm i gulp`).

My question is :

- How can I find the cause of this error and how can I fix it?

I've tried deleting the entire dir in `%APPDATA%/Code`, so the cache seems to be cleared. Then, I restarted VSCode. But the problem persists.

Comment: I've copied your `tasks.json` into mine `.vscode/` and `all` task runs just fine. 1) Can you create a minimal reproducible example? 2) Try to create a new project and run tasks in it, does the problem persists? 3) What's VSCode version?

Comment: I'm a little bit confused. After reading your comment and question again, I've noticed that: "If I move the `.vscode/tasks.json` file to another directory **on my computer**, the task `all` runs just fine" should probably answer my quesition #2 with `No, then there is no problem`, but then you wrote "**but not on my main computer**" + answered my question #2 with "**Yes**". Can you clarify?

Comment: Format? Does this mean that you've already tried to reinstall VSCode in no vain?

Comment: (Sorry, I really rushed my comment a there) I meant to say it works in another directory (so obviously it also works on a different computer). Yes, I have already tried to reinstall VSCode. To ranswer your questions properly; 1) I cannot create a minimal, reproducible example. 2) Creating a new project (in the same directory) does not solve the issue. 3) The VSCode version is 1.46.1.

Comment: What I'm really asking here is where would errors appear? VSCode itself does not show any errors whatsoever, just complete "silence" when I run the task. I'm not just looking to solve the issue, I'm keen on knowing how to debug this.

Comment: Don't know if it's possible to answer this question with this little details, and I don't know how much more is needed. But about debugging `VSCode` itself: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/7828 does this helps?

Comment: It appears this conversation is task centric, when you've already proven those same configurations work perfectly on the same computer, with the same vscode version, just in a different directory. If it works everywhere but there, what's different about that directory? It appears this isn't a tasks issue at all, but I think the question is still good "how can I find the error". Do you have any settings configured in that workspace that would conflict?

Comment: So I've done some more experiments with this, and it seems I was wrong. It's not the directory that is the problem. It is the running parallel tasks when gulp is installed. I'm going to try this some more and create a minimal example where I can make the error occur.

Comment: Hmm, can't really pinpoint the error but something about my setup makes it impossible to run parellel tasks when gulp is involved. Again, no error message or anything. Just nothing happens when I try to launch the task. Note that tasks work exactly as they should, just not parallel tasks doesn't.

Comment: `parallel`? As in, you are running some kind of code or service outside the workspace in addition to? Or do you mean consecutively (`dependsOn`) @gromit190

Comment: I mean parallel as in using the `dependsOn` property. I see that the error only occurs when `gulp` is installed for the project (using `npm i gulp`).

Comment: I've edited my original question.

Comment: is that folder having task is shared ?

Comment: No, it does not.

Comment: For anyone interested the problem is described here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/112207. But my question still stands, how was I supposed to find this error that occured in VSCode?